# « Se venir » : sens (Messieurs les Ronds-de-cuir, Georges Courteline)

Tags: sens, verbes-pronominaux

> D’abord hésitante, vagabonde, sa folie chaque jour grandissante s’était venue, enfin et définitivement, fixer en un chaos d’âpre misanthropie qu’une admiration désordonnée de l’Antiquité compliquait, sans que l’on sût pourquoi.

On ne trouve pas ce verbe pronominal au TLFi.

Est-ce que l'ajout du pronom personnel modifie le sens du verbe ?

Comment: Tu trouveras la réponse dans LBU pronom personnels parties du discours - infinitif objet d'un verbe qui précède (dans l'hist.) Fréquent dans la littérature classique. Courteline aime bien ce tour (*une deuxième ardoise ... s’était venue planter ...*) Ex. trouvé dans le TLF *Une Madame de Pontcarré, dévote de bel air, qui s'était venue loger à Port-Royal...*.

Comment: @None Courteline apparemment affectionne particuliérement toutes ces inversions ("_l'aller_ ...").

Comment: Mais je vois aussi qu'il y a une tournure s'en venir encore d'actualité au Québec, peut-être pas dans le sens de l'expression utilisée par Courteline, qui est plutôt s'en venir + verbe.

Comment: @Frank *S'en venir* c'est tout autre chose (ça veut dire *arriver* et je l'entends encore où je vis), dans la question de l'OP le *se* c'est le se de  *se fixer* comme tu le dis dans ta réponse.

Comment: @None Oui, oui bien reçu, c'est pour ça que j'avais ajouté une _incise_ (? :-) "peut-être pas dans le sens...". En fait, je devrais peut-être enlever mon commentaire pour ne pas introduire de confusion inutile?

Comment: @Frank Hmmm Ne confonds-tu pas ici [*incise*](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/proposition-incise) et [incidente](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/incidente) ??  On peut dire qu'une proposition incise est une forme d'incidente, mais le contraire n'est pas vrai.  [incise et incidente](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect6&info0=6.1.9)

Comment: @None oui, je confonds sans doute - j'avais un doute, et c'est pour ça que j'avais mis un "(? :-)". Bon allez, je vais m'éduquer sur les _incises_ et les _incidentes_, merci des liens!

Comment: @None Tu as absolument raison, il ne s'agit pas d'une incise mais d'une incidente.

Comment: *[...] car il s'est venu excuser de son péché*, François Le Picart, 1567.

Comment: En plus le LBU de FrenchPDF que tu as permet une recherche plein texte...

Answer (score 3):

L'ordre des mots est différent de ce que l'on dirait plus couramment de nos jours, mais cela signifie: *chaque jour, sa folie grandissante était venue **se fixer**, enfin et définitivement, en un chaos...*

Comment: @jiliagre Merci pours les corrections! :-)

Comment: Avis aux visiteurs  : Il n'y a aucune raison que cette réponse ait été moinssoyée car elle est parfaitement exacte. *se* est COD de l'infinitif fixer, lorsque le pronom personnel objet est construit avec deux verbes qui se suivent, le second étant à l'infinitif, en ancien français ce pp  se plaçait devant les deux verbes. (Régnier, Études d’ancien français. Moyen Âge et XVIe siècle. p. 338 https://archive.org/details/MarcelGalliotEtudesDAncienFrancais/mode/2up).

Comment: La langue littéraire n'a pas abandonné ce tour, (notamment avec pouvoir, vouloir, venir, savoir etc.) Ex donnés dans LBU ( parties du discours/pronoms personnels/autre mode que l'impératif) : *Il avait dû s'aller changer* (Martin du Gard), *Un parc où se peuvent chasser touts sortes de gibier* (Bazin)

Comment: D'ailleurs, je vais l'aller utiliser derechef, car oui, elle se peut encor utiliser. Tout cela se peut écrire, sans même trop y travailler, mais en 2023, ça fait un peu vieux, non?